# Can you use Python3/Selenium to open my browser with plugins?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have plug ins with login credentials/API keys I want to be using in the Chrome browser when python/selenium opens a new window.

However, currently when my code opens the browser, it's a new Chrome window without any extensions.

How do I get it to point towards opening the default browser, as if I was opening Chrome?

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def perform_login_logout(url, username, password, new_url):
    # Set the path to your Chrome driver executable


    # Create an instance of Chrome WebDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Open the URL to the login page
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: To open the default Chrome browser with all installed plugins in Python using Selenium, you can make use of Chrome user profiles.By specifying a user profile in Selenium, you can launch Chrome with the desired plugins and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by setting the `user_data_dir` via `options`.

`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=%s" % path_to_user_data_dir)`

A full example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=%s" % path_to_user_data_dir)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Marking as answered